# How to schedule a MySQL database backup in a remote Ubuntu server to a Dropbox folder in Windows PC?

Tags: mysql, batch-file, dropbox, remote-backup

I have a MySQL database that I want to daily backup to my Dropbox folder on my Windows PC.

How can I do that automatically from Windows 7?

Comment: [Have you triead anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Hint: Don't even think about copying individual files from MySQL data folder

Comment: @Barranka Thanks for your advice. Please take me as an example of developers who blog/share their techniques and knowledge via stackoverflow questions.

Comment: @Barranka And my question is the starting point for my blog. Except a better solution from the community shows up, I'll start applying my thoughts and will soon return here with my full answer to my own question. You can see my question on downloading standalone Visual Studio and hope you would see how such guys like me contribute to this great and open communitty! NOT all of us here are dummy as you may think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to extract a backup and push it onto Dropbox is as below.

A sample of Ubuntu batch file can be downloaded [here](https://db.tt/YSZ7VAbc).

### In brief

1. Prepare a batch script `backup.sh`
2. Run `backup.sh` to create a backup version e.g. `backup.sql`
3. Copy `backup.sql` to Dropbox folder
4. Schedule Ubuntu/Windows task to run `backup.sh` task e.g. every day at night

### Detail steps

1. All about backing up and restoring an MySQL database can be found [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/mysql_backup_restore.php).

> Back up to compressed file
>
> mysqldump -u [uname] -p [dbname] | gzip -9 > [backupfile.sql.gz]

2. How to remote from Windows to execute the 'backup' command can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/a/217071/41015).

> plink.exe -ssh -pw  -i "Path\to\private-key\key.ppk" -noagent username@server-ip

3. How to bring the file to Dropbox can be found [here](http://xmodulo.com/2013/09/access-dropbox-command-line-linux.html)

> Create a app
>   https://www2.dropbox.com/developers/apps
>
> Add an app and choose `Dropbox API App`. Note the created `app key` and `app secret`
>
> Install Dropbox API in Ubuntu; use app key and app secret above
>
> ```
> $ wget https://raw.github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader/master/dropbox_uploader.sh
> $ chmod +x dropbox_uploader.sh
> ```
>
> Follow the instruction to authorize access for the app e.g.
>
> ```
> http://www2.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=XXXXXXX
> ```
>
> Test the app if it is working right - should be ok
>
> ```
> $ ./dropbox_uploader.sh info
> ```
>
> The app is created and a folder associating with it is `YourDropbox\Apps\<app name>`
>
> Commands to use
>
> List files
>
> ```
> $ ./dropbox_uploader.sh list
> ```
>
> Upload file
>
> ```
> $ ./dropbox_uploader.sh upload <filename> <dropbox location>
> e.g.
> $ ./dropbox_uploader.sh upload backup.sql .
> ```
>
> This will store file `backup.sql` to `YourDropbox\Apps\<app name>\backup.sql`
>
> Done

4. How to schedule a Ubuntu can be view [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) using `crontab`

> Call command
>
> ```
> sudo crontab -e
> ```
>
> Insert a line to run backup.sh script everyday as below
>
> ```
> 0 0 * * * /home/userName/pathTo/backup.sh
> ```
>
> Explaination:
>
> ```
> minute (0-59), hour (0-23, 0 = midnight), day (1-31), month (1-12), weekday (0-6, 0 = Sunday), command
> ```
>
> Or simply we can use
>
> ```
> @daily /home/userName/pathTo/backup.sh
> ```

Note:

- To mornitor crontab tasks, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/121560/22308) is a very good guide.
  [image]

Comment: Your link in `2.` above is to `plink.exe` not anything about how to do anything.

Comment: I must remind you that "link-only" answers are discouraged, because the content's of a web page can change (or even get deleted over time). Please include the relevant parts of your solution, so other users can benefit from it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Tkank you! I've fixed the link.

Comment: @Barranka Yeah, of course it is. I'll put a copy of information in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

One of the simplest ways to backup a mysql database is by creating a dump file. And that is what `mysqldump` is for. Please [read the documentation for `mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html).

In its simplest syntax, you can create a dump with the following command:

```
mysqldump [connection parameters] database_name > dump_file.sql
```

where the `[connection parameters]` are those you need to connect your local client to the MySQL server where the database resides.

`mysqldump` will create a dump file: a plain text file which contains the SQL instructions needed to create and populate the tables of a database. The `>` character will redirect the output of `mysqldump` to a file (in this example, `dump_file.sql`). You can, of course, compress this file to make it more easy to handle.

You can move that file wherever you want.

To restore a dump file:

1. Create an empty database (let's say `restore`) in the destination server
2. Load the dump:

   `mysql [connection parameters] restore < dump_file.sql`

---

There are, of course, some other "switches" you can use with `mysqldump`. I frequently use these:

- `-d`: this wil tell `mysqldump` to create an "empty" backup: the tables and views will be exported, but without data (useful if all you want is a database "template")
- `-R`: include the stored routines (procedures and functions) in the dump file
- `--delayed-insert`: uses `insert delayed` instead of `insert` for populating tables
- `--disable-keys`: Encloses the `insert` statements for each table between `alter table ... disable keys` and `alter table ... enable keys`; this can make inserts faster

---

You can include the `mysqldump` command and any other compression and copy / move command in a batch file.

Comment: Great explanation from you! Thank you!